# Countdown timer loop with an action

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to set a countdown timer for 30s seconds. After 30 seconds I want it to do (whatever) and then loop and start the 30 second countdown again.

Comment: sorry i am not clear about your question you need delay 30 seconds delay ? can u give more clarity your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
    {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            tv_timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            //do your stuff and at end of that stuff again call CountDownTimer method
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final int delay = 30 * 1000; //30 secs

private void startCountDown(){
   mHandler.postDelayed(task, delay); 
}

private Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //do something...

        if (true) { //condition to continue...
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }
};
```